# Output vanishes in op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, function-generator

The circuit below is a PW modulating circuit:

[image]

The output of the circuit is:

[image]

But when I connect a resitive load to the output of the op-amp. The output vanishes:

[image]

Can someone explain why is it happening so?

Comment: The word "op-amp" is an abbreviation of "operational-amplifier". It's not an initialisation so it doesn't get capital letters.

Comment: Is it so,Thank you.

Comment: What about my question?

Comment: It may depend on the value of the resistive load.

Comment: U2 and B1 are not connected to ground.

Comment: Yes you were right the error was not connecting the ground.Thank you.

Comment: Please accept my answer below to indicate that the question has been answered / solved.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. B1 and U2 are missing their ground connection.*